# Flow through manifold: convergence issues

Tags: cfd, fluent

I try to simulate flow through a manifold with multiple inlets & outlets but I'm facing convergence issues.

I know that it may be due to poor quality mesh, but my mesh statistics are:

- Minimum Orthogonal Quality =  0.115844
- Maximum Ortho Skew =  0.853992
- Maximum Aspect Ratio =  31.8148e

which doesn't look that bad to me.

Another point could be due to wrong BCs and I'm not sure wether my BCs are good. For the inlets I calculated mass flow in the domain (since the manifold is a physical part from a measurement system, I know roughly what the flow field looks like and what the flow in and out my domain is) and set it as **mass-flow-inlet** BC. For the outlets I also calculated mass flow and set it as **pressure-outlet** with a good guess for the initial gauge pressure and a **target-mass-flow**.

But as I said, I don't get a converged solution, is it due to these BCs?

I attach some residual plots.
(I wanted to add more but I can only post 2 links...)

If you need more information let me know, I tried to keep it short.

[image: residuals]
[image: mass-flow outlet-1]

Comment: After looking at the result in CFD-Post, the flow field looks like expected. But I'm still unsure about the convergence

Comment: Pressure based or density based? Did you try different turbulence models? Did you use relaxation factors?

Comment: Pressure based, I tried only k-omega with low Re-correction and URFs are:
pressure 0.3
density 1
momentum 0.7
turbulent kinetic energy 0.7
specific dissipation rate 0.7
turbulent viscosity 0.9
O2 0.9
NO2 0.9
energy 0.95

So I lowered some URFs, but what should I change to get continuity down?

Comment: 1 - You should not be using mass-flow inlet BC with pressure based problems, calculate the velocity from the flow rate and use velocity-inlet BC. 2 - Can you attach a picture of the geometry? Or are you having outlets close to inlets?

Comment: I will try it with velocity inlets, and here is a picture from my geometry/mesh
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-31971232/mesh.png.html